# Apple alternative to Google Sign-in

Tags: android, ios, authentication

I'm building an app for both Android and iOS. Users should be able to login but I don't want to deal with their passwords myself and want to use third party sign-in. I already implemented Google sign-in on Android (https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating) and iOS but since I'm not sure how many iPhone users have a Google account I was wondering whether there is an Apple alternative. Can I use the Apple ID or maybe iCloud account for this purpose?

Comment: By google account you mean gmail? basically if you have a gmail account you have a google account...So I guess the answer to that question is almost every user..

Comment: Yes exactly, when people have a gmail account they have a google account. But I'm guessing the number of gmail users on iOS will be a lot lower than on Android.

Comment: And what brings you to that guess?

Comment: I am not sure about this...I (and basically everyone I know) use a gmail as their default email in apple ID.

Comment: Ok, that's good news I guess since then I can get away with only the google sign-in. I guess a good metric would be the number of Gmail app downloads on Android/iOS. Are there any numbers publicly available for this? I only can find the number for Android (2.5 million).

Comment: You could also use Game Center for iOS, or Facebook.